# Looping through previous or next rows and do calculation - Python

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe as follows,

```
ID  response    time
1   1315     1.434054
2   1682     3.753334
2   2829     5.940094
3   184      6.243214
4   243      6.301918
3   1413     7.486633
5   2400    11.474644
6   2151     3.288531
```

the Dataframe has an ID, response and time.

For examples that do not have duplicates in ID (1,4,5,6), I want to return the time.
For examples that do have duplicates in  ID(2,3), I want to return the minimum of the two times in the min_time column AND the difference between the two times in difference column. The following is the output I am looking at,

```
    ID       response    time      min_time     difference
     1         1315     1.434054    1.434054        NA
     2         1682     3.753334    3.753334      2.18676
     2         2829     5.940094    3.753334      2.18676
     3          184     6.243214    6.243214      1.243419
     4          243     6.301918    6.301918         NA
     3         1413     7.486633    6.243214      1.243419
     5         2400    11.474644    11.474644        NA
     6         2151     3.288531    3.288531         NA
```

While I am able to bring this output using loops, it is not the best efficient way to do it and also it takes a lot of time. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly way that involves building a dictionary of the minimum times for each ID. You didn't provide your solution to this problem, so it's hard for me to compare this to what you did, but this doesn't run too slowly.

```
data = {}

with open(path) as File:
    for line in File:
        ID, response, time = line.split()
        if ID in data:
            data[ID].append([response, time])
        else:
            data.update({ID: [[response, time]]})

minTimes = {}
for ID, value in data.items():
    if len(value) > 1:
        for i, j in enumerate(value):
            if ID in minTimes:
                if value[i][1] < minTimes[ID]:
                    minTimes[ID] = value[i][1]
            else:
                minTimes[ID] = value[i][1]
    else:
        minTimes[ID] = 'NA'

for ID, value in data.items():
    for i, j in enumerate(value):
        if minTimes[ID] != 'NA':
            value[i] =  [
                            int(value[i][0]),
                            float(value[i][1]),
                            float(minTimes[ID]),
                            abs(float(value[i][1]) - float(minTimes[ID]))
                        ]
        else:
            value[i] =  [
                            int(value[i][0]),
                            float(value[i][1]),
                            float(value[i][1]),
                            minTimes[ID]
                        ]

print(data)
```

I'll leave it to you to format the output. While I was working with it I just used json.dumps to make it print nicely, but if you want it to be in the same format you used in your question, you'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: This is not exactly a memory-optimal solution, but it will work.   If you find yourself working with larger data-sets, consider the idea that you don't need to store every time along the way, just the shortest time for each ID, if you don't mind two passes through the data.  One to collect min's, one to output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df['min_time'] = df.groupby('ID')['time'].transform(lambda x: x.min())

df['difference'] = df.groupby('ID')['time'].transform(lambda x: x.max()-x.min()).replace(0,np.nan)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ID  response       time   min_time  difference
0   1      1315   1.434054   1.434054         NaN
1   2      1682   3.753334   3.753334    2.186760
2   2      2829   5.940094   3.753334    2.186760
3   3       184   6.243214   6.243214    1.243419
4   4       243   6.301918   6.301918         NaN
5   3      1413   7.486633   6.243214    1.243419
6   5      2400  11.474644  11.474644         NaN
7   6      2151   3.288531   3.288531         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ? also beside this , you can also try `transform` in `Pandas`

```
funcs = dict(min_time  ='min', difference=np.ptp)
d1 = df.join(df.groupby(['ID']).time.agg(funcs), on=['ID'])
d1.loc[d1.difference==0]=np.nan

Out[27]: 
    ID  respon       time   min_time  difference
0  1.0  1315.0   1.434054   1.434054         NaN
1  2.0  1682.0   3.753334   3.753334    2.186760
2  2.0  2829.0   5.940094   3.753334    2.186760
3  3.0   184.0   6.243214   6.243214    1.243419
4  4.0   243.0   6.301918   6.301918         NaN
5  3.0  1413.0   7.486633   6.243214    1.243419
6  5.0  2400.0  11.474644  11.474644         NaN
7  6.0  2151.0   3.288531   3.288531         NaN
```